# ES6 object destructuring clarification using React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a question regarding object destructuring in JS. In the code below I would assume that the component Layout would have been assigned the value layout (with lowercase). However the value of layout is undefined and Layout is being used.

```
const MustBeAuthenticated = ({ layout: Layout, ...rest }) => {
  if (!isAuthenticated()) {
    return redirectToLogin({...rest})
  }
  return (
    <Layout {...rest} />
  )
}
```

I tried to then extract the component using `({ Layout, ...rest })` but I get thrown a undefined error again. I just wanted some clarification if I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: No you are actually right. However i dont see a sense in doing `{...rest}`, `rest` would be enough

Comment: It's `...rest` which is throwing an error not `Layout`, which is correct

Comment: I guess my main question is regarding `{ layout: Layout }`, I would of assumed that `layout` would be accessible and not `Layout`. Is there come react magic happening behind the scenes that is causing this capitalisation?

Comment: Check my answer, you have to clone the layout if you want to add props to it. Otherwise if you don't have props in layout before you call this function don't bother passing it in and just import Layout and use it directly instead of making it a parameter.

Comment: Clearly my misunderstanding was due to the reverse order of the destructuring. I always understood destructuring as following a JSON-esk design using `key: value`.  A little counter intuitive in my opinion but @mahesh gave a clear example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function logmsg({logMessage: LogMessage, ...rest}) {
    console.log(LogMessage); // prints 'hi'
    console.log(rest); // prints {bye: 'bye'}
}

logmsg({logMessage: 'hi', bye: 'bye'});
```

This works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to want to use [cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) from the React API. You have layout stored in a variable, if you want to return it you need to use it, not the Layout Component.

Something like this:

```
const MustBeAuthenticated = ({layout, ...rest}) => {
  if (!isAuthenticated()) {
    return redirectToLogin({...rest})
  }
  return (
    React.cloneElement(
      layout,
      rest,
    )
  )
}
```

That will give you something like this

```
<element.type {...element.props} {...props}>{children}</element.type>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `:` inside object destructuring is assigning the value to a new variable name.

```js
var {a:aa} = {a: 3};

console.log(aa);
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variables_names_and_providing_default_values